# Failed to process JAR [jar:jndi:/localhost/ttsvr/WEB-INF/lib/activation.jar!/null] for TLD files

Tags: tomcat, tooltwist

I'm deploying a ToolTwist application to a production server using FIP, and get the following error in catalina.out when I start the server.

> INFO: Deploying web application directory ttsvr 06/07/2012 3:51:02 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
>   WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:jndi:/localhost/ttsvr/WEB-INF/lib/activation.jar!/null] for TLD files
>   java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
>           at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>           at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
>           at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
>           at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1828)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:204)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           ...

It's a warning rather than an error, and the application seems to run fine, but it displays the full stack trace on every jar file and puts 3,700 lines in the log file.

The jar files do exists, and have the correct file permissions. I've tried deleting jar files, checked server.xml and web.xml. The application has run before on other servers.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.12, java 1.7, and ToolTwist V8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error can occur if the tomcat/temp directory goes missing.

I'm not sure how you're copying the files to your production server, but possibly it's not creating empty directories.

Answer (score 3):

Answer was really helpful. Silly error but yea adding temp directory inside tomcat resolved the issue

Comment: Where should one put the temp directory?

Comment: It works for me too: creating a folder named "temp" in tomcat home (apache-tomcat-7.0.12\temp). I just cannot figure why tomcat does not create it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried unzipping the `jar` file that was reported in the logs and unzipping processes showed me that a certain `file` within the `jar` was `corrupted`. Fixing `corrupted file` solved all other issues.